# MySQL trigger abort

Tags: php, mysql, database

MyIsam DB

To be specific, I insert into one table 5-10 rows at the time usually. After inserts are done, I want to get COUNT(DISTINCT(column)) and SUM(some_other_column) of the newly inserted rows and insert it into another table.

How I figured this might be done (but I don't know if it can) is to make a trigger on after insert and then make one select on table where I inserted the rows, insert it into another table and break trigger's for loop.

Suggestions please. I feel bad about this somehow.

Comment: If you haven't gone through the manual yet, with examples https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- Can you point me more specific. I am kinda short on time. Is this a good way to achieve what I want?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I understand this, but this only solves the SUM() part of my problem. What about the columns where I need to get COUNT(DISTINCT(column))?